# Heap corruption when calling destructor of class with const_iterator member

Tags: c++, heap-corruption

I have a class with a deque of strings and an iterator as members.
There's a `GetNext()`method that gives me the next element and increments the iterator. Using the class from outside I check for an empty string to indicate the end of the deque.
Unfortunately I get a Heap corruption when the constructor is called and the last element was gotten using GetNext.
I suppose this happens because after the last string (empty string) in the deque, the iterator is still incremented and points *somewhere* in memory?
So that the destructor then tries to free this memory and then crashes?

```
   #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <deque>


class Foo 
{
public:
    Foo()
    {
        list.push_back("first elm");
        list.push_back("second elm");
        list.push_back(std::string());      
        pNextItem = list.begin();
    }

    virtual ~Foo(){}

    const std::string& GetNext() { return *pNextItem++; }

protected:

    std::deque<std::string> list;
    std::deque<std::string>::const_iterator pNextItem;
};


int main()
{
  {
  Foo foo;
  std::cout << foo.GetNext() << std::endl; //  "first elm"
  std::cout << foo.GetNext() << std::endl; //  "second elm"
  std::cout << foo.GetNext() << std::endl; //  ""
  //third call sets the iterator past the last element and causes a segfault
  std::cout << foo.GetNext() << std::endl;

  }

}
```

Here's an example:
[Compilable and executable Example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMUG5VdlBZa1BDMzA)

Comment: I edited the example to include usage and a link to  compilable code on tutorialspoint.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to check if `pNextItem` is equal to `list.cend()` before dereferencing. This is exactly what happens after the third call of `foo.GetNext()` when you will dereference the last element and increment the iterator.

From `deque::end` [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/end):

> Returns an iterator to the element following the last element of the
>   container.
>
> This element acts as a placeholder; attempting to access it results in
>   undefined behavior.

Comment: Very well guessed ;) Thanks for the answer. Would this be a good way instead? : 
`const std::string& GetNext()
{
 if (pNextItem == list.end())
  return *pNextItem;

 return *pNextItem++;
}`

Comment: no, you will still try to dereference `list.cend()` which is UB. So either return a special value (like empty string), or use return codes/exceptions/optional to identify that you reached the end of your container.

Comment: Thanks, of course... checking for the empty string element now
`const std::string& GetNext()
{
 if (pNextItem->empty())
  return *pNextItem;

 return *pNextItem++;
}`